# How to do a fit with a Split Pearson 7 function in Python?

Tags: python, model-fitting, lmfit

I have an asymmetric peak that I want to fit using a split Pearson 7 (SP7) function with lmfit.
First, the SP7 function has been defined, then I re-called it with lmfit, but at the end I have this error: ValueError: varargs '*p' is not supported. Why?

````
def polynomial(x, *p):
    poly = Polynomial(p)
    y = poly(x)
    return y

def pearson7(x, *p):
    x0, IM, H, m = p
    y = IM / (1+4*(2**(1/m)-1)*(x-x0)**2/H**2)**m
    return y

def splitpearson7(x, *p):
    x0, IM, Hl, ml, Hr, mr = p
    pl = [x0, IM, Hl, ml]
    pr = [x0, IM, Hr, mr]
    y = pearson7(x, *pl)*np.heaviside(x-x0, 0.5) + pearson7(x, *pr)*np.heaviside(x0-x, 0.5)
    return y

def splitpearson7_backg(x, *p):
    """
    Split PearsonVII distribution with linear background (8 parameters)
    * background y = A + Bx
    """
    y = splitpearson7(x, *p[0:6]) + polynomial(x, *p[6:8])
    return y ```

first_params_fit=[0, np.max(y), 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.5, 10, 0.3]
mod = Model(splitpearson7_backg)
pars = mod.make_params(first_params_fit)
result = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(result.fit_report()) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ValueError: varargs '*p' is not supported.
```

Indeed.

`Why?`

Well, partly because it is a horrible way to define a function, and partly because it breaks the concept of `lmfit.Model` to be able to determine ***and name*** parameters for your model function.   In short: readability counts.   Do the person reading your code (including your future self) a favor and write readable code.

With your `splitpearson7` the meaning and order of the parameters for the function are lost.  The order is still critical of course, but it is not described in any way.  It does not even say how many parameters there are.  If, instead, you used

```
def splitpearson7(x, x0, IM, Hl, ml, Hr, mr):
    pl = [x0, IM, Hl, ml]
    pr = [x0, IM, Hr, mr]
    y = pearson7(x, *pl)*np.heaviside(x-x0, 0.5) + pearson7(x, *pr)*np.heaviside(x0-x, 0.5)
    return y
```

then you could create a `lmfit.Model` with

```
 sp7_model = lmfit.Model(splitpearson7)
```

and have named parameters:

```
 params = sp7_model.make_params(x0=0, IM=1, Hl=2, ml=3.3, Hr=2.1, mr=5)
```

Indeed, your `pearson7` function could also use named parameters.  Or, you could use the version builtin to `lmfit`:

```
from lmfit.lineshapes import pearson7
def splitpearson7(x, center, amplitude, sigma_left, m_left, sigma_right, m_right):
      left = heaviside(x-center, 0.5)*pearson7(x, amplitude, center, sigma_left, m_left) 
      right = heaviside(center-x, 0.5)*pearson7(x, amplitude, center, sigma_right, m_right) 
      return left+right
```

In addition, it is generally "the lmfit Model way" to not build a model that adds a function with a background, but to make a composite model, as with

```
from numpy import heaviside
from lmfit.lineshapes import pearson7
from lmfit.model import Model
from lmfit.models import PolynomialModel

def splitpearson7(x, center, amplitude, sigma_left, m_left, sigma_right, m_right):
    left = heaviside(x-center, 0.5)*pearson7(x, amplitude, center, sigma_left, m_left) 
    right = heaviside(center-x, 0.5)*pearson7(x, amplitude, center, sigma_right, m_right) 
    return left+right

# Note that PolynomialModel(2) will be quadratic with parameters 
# c0, c1, c2, and a form = c0 + c1*x + c2*x*x
mod = Model(splitpearson7) + PolynomialModel(2)
params = mod.make_params(center=0, amplitude=200, 
                         sigma_left=2, m_left=1, 
                         sigma_right=2.2, m_right=1.1, 
                         c0=10, c1=0, c2=0)
```

That will make it much easier to alter the model for the background.

Comment: I wrote the code as you suggested, but I got this message: 
`ValueError: The model function generated NaN values and the fit aborted! Please check your model function and/or set boundaries on parameters where applicable. In cases like this, using "nan_policy='omit'" will probably not work.`